# Link images to a c# program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little problem with my c# program.
I need to change the image of a picturebox in the code, so I used

```
Image Sign = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\Pictures\\GoStraight.png");
```

and then

```
ImageBox.Image=Sign;
```

It does work, but if I change the file location or go to another PC, the program starts with an error message.
I somehow want to link the images to my program so that the programlocation
doesnt really care (like if the program is on F:, E: or C:).
Could you plese tell me a way to do that? That would be Great!

Comment: What kind of application are you targeting ? WinForm, WPF ?

Comment: Have you tried putting the image in your Resources?  Then you can access it using AppName.Properties.Resources.GoStraight

Comment: You should store the path of your images in the configuration file. Then read it from there. If you need to change the path you could update only the config file

Comment: I am targeting a WinForm

Comment: No,I haven't tried to put it in Resources. Didn`t know that it is possible.. Can you tell me how?

Comment: Oh sorry haven`t seen that there were already solutions.

Comment: Hmm, the solution is shown in Visual C# (i think), but I am using SharpDevelop. I tried to add a new Resource but I wasn`t able until now.

Comment: Nice, found it. Thx foryour help!